# Fetch dynamic URL after logged in with Google Identity Services in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, google-identity

What I need to do is to be able to log in with GIS, and then fetch an URL that would end with the {user.email} we just got from decoding the JWT.

Here is my code :

```
   interface userI {
        name: string | null;
        iat?: number;
        iss?: string;
        picture?: string;
        email?: string;
    }

    interface bookingI {
        id: number;
        bureau: string;
        aile: string;
        office: string;
        office_id: string;
        cote: string;
        time: Date;
        etage: string;
        direction: string;
        espace: string;
    }


    const [ user, setUser] = useState<userI>({name: null});
    
    function handleCallbackResponse(response: any) {
        console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
        var userObject = jwt_decode(response.credential);
        console.log(userObject);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userObject))
        setUser(userObject as userI);
        document.getElementById("signInDiv")!.hidden = true;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            /* global google */
                //@ts-ignore
            google.accounts.id.initialize({
                client_id: "myId",
                callback: handleCallbackResponse
            });
            
                //@ts-ignore
            google.accounts.id.renderButton(
                document.getElementById("signInDiv"),
                { theme: "outline", size: "large", shape: "pill"}
            );
            },[]);


        


    const [booking, setBooking] = useState<bookingI>();
            const apiUrl = "apiUrl"
            
    useEffect(() => {
            
            const api = async () => {
                
            const data = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/${user.email}`, {
                  method: "GET"
            });
            const jsonData = await data.json();       
                console.log("jsonData : ")
                console.log(jsonData)

                setBooking(jsonData.data);

            };

            api();
        
            },[]);
```

What I have been able to do so far : Log in with GIS, decoding JWT and display {user.email} it in return, fetch my API NOT dynamically ("url/myemail").

What I did not manage to do : Be able to fetch (`url/${user.email}`) the moment login with GIS was successful (and not before), stay signed in even after refreshing (maybe it's the problem I need to fix).

Pretty new to Typescript, thank you for your patience and consideration.

Comment: Simply removing the second useEffect makes things work but now I have an infinite loop, we don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

```js
const userEmail = user.email
const fullUrl = `${apiUrl}/${userEmail}`
            
useEffect(() => {
  const api = async () => {
  //console.log(fullUrl)
  const data = await fetch(`${fullUrl}`, {
    method: "GET"
  });
  
  const jsonData = await data.json();       
    //console.log("jsonData : ")
    //console.log(jsonData)
    console.log("Extractable data : ")
    console.log(jsonData.data)
            
    setBooking(jsonData.data);

  };
  if (userEmail !== undefined){
    api();
  }
},[fullUrl, userEmail]);
```

I still need to stay signed in even after refreshing but my main problem is solved